# Java: Problems reading/writing UTF-8 .csv file saved in Excel

Tags: java, excel, csv, encoding, vaadin

I'm working on a Java application that accepts .csv files from the user, then reads and writes them to a temp folder on the server to do some processing.  Here's some of my IO code:

```
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));

            String str;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(str);
                out.newLine();
            }
            out.flush();
```

When debugging here and looking at the output file in Excel, it looks exactly as I expect.  Let's say that the user inputs a csv file where the first cell's value is "Foo" (no special characters); that all seems to appear in Excel and the debugger.  But later, I'll parse the output file for that value, just using `value.contains("Foo")`.  This returns false only when the csv file is saved in csv UTF-8 format in Excel, even though according to Excel and the debugger value has a value of "Foo".

Why would this happen?

Comment: `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` are best created with an explicit `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` or `Charset.defaultCharset()` (which is the default). `out.write("\uFEFF");` before the loop might help to recognize UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

problem could be when you later read the file, you have to read it in "UTF-8" encoding like

```
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```